# Semilinear elliptic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, convexity, semi-linear-elliptic-pdes

Assume $u$ is a smooth solution for
$$
\Delta u + f(u)=0\qquad \hbox{in}\quad \Omega
$$
and $\Omega$ is a smooth convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there a conjecture which are the weakest conditions on f under which the solution has convex superlevels?

Background to the question: In the 1980s, there was work by Acker, Caffarelli, Friedman, Spruck and others on this topic.  However, the conditions at f are very different in each case. In the meantime there is also a counterexample by Hamel, Nadirashvili and Sire for the case f=-1.

Comment: At least, you need some convexity (concavity ?) For, if $f=\lambda u$ is linear, then $u$ may oscillate even under the zero Dirichlet boundary condition (just take $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $-\Delta$, not the first one).

Comment: What is "the solution"? This equation can have many solutions.